# What type of header is needed for a door opening in load bearing concrete wall?

Tags: doors

I  have a walkout basement with a covered front porch 4'x 9', so the space under the porch is surrounded with concrete 9" walls.  I want to cut a door in the basement in the concrete wall, empty the gravel and other stuff from that space and turn the space into a storm shelter.  I will cut a small door in the 4' section which I enter through a closet.  The wall is load bearing as above it is a concrete slab, and 10' of brick.  What do I need to use for a header"?

Comment: You're probably going to want to contact a structural engineer, instead of a bunch of yahoos on the internet.

Answer (score 4):

Don't head off half cocked with internet advice and a 10" brick wall above. Hire a structural/civil engineer, and get an answer you can bet your house and/or life on - because you will be doing exactly that. Having got the advice, follow it carefully.

Given that you say "small door" your engineer might be able to give you a less painful solution by using a round-topped door that will act somewhat like an arch, for instance.